# Could I cluster the audio clips in order to improve the speed of their classification?

Tags: deep-learning, tensorflow, clustering, embeddings, audio-processing

I have a neural network which is very resource intensive and is used to classify audio clips. The classification is done in batches, where I record for a set period of time and then go through and classify the audio.

However, the time for classification is far too long.

So I was thinking what if I could somehow embed the audio and then cluster them into similar audio files. This way I'd only need to classify a couple audio clips in the cluster and assume they're all the same.

Is this possible?

All suggestion, improvements or help is very much appreciated!

Comment: Can you be more specific? Why is the classification slow? Is it because there are a lot of audio clips?

Comment: @DKDK The time of detection of clip > the audio length of the recording

Comment: It sounds like something that is possible, yes.

Comment: The clustering will need to do similar processing as the classifier, if it is to work any good at all. I think you are much better off optimizing your neural network

Comment: What neural network are you using? Number of parameters?

Comment: Are you using batching? Multi-processing?